# Description of Blow up via Ress Algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, graded-rings, blowup

Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be an affine scheme and $Z=\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ defined by an ideal $I$ of $R$. The blow up of $X$ along  $Z$ is (say)$\mathrm{Bl}_{Z}(X)=\mathrm{Proj}(\bar{R})$, where $\bar{R}$ is the Rees algebra of $I$ over $R$, i.e., $\bar{R}=R \oplus I +\oplus I^2 \oplus I^3 \oplus \cdots $.

The blow-map $\mathrm{Bl}_Z(X)\rightarrow X$ is given by the natural ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow \bar{R}$.

**My question is:** How does the natural ring inclusion $R\rightarrow \bar{R}$ to give rise to a map $\mathrm{Proj}(\bar{R})\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(R)$?

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with the blowup then — you always have a structure morphism $\operatorname{Proj} S \to \operatorname{Spec} S_0$.

Comment: Is this the blow up map?

Comment: Yes. I think the thing to notice is that there are natural maps $S_0 \to (S_f)_0$ for the homogeneous elements $f \in S_+$. So you get maps out of members of an affine cover of Proj and indeed they are compatible.